# Laravel : Define model for reverse OneToMany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have the following schema:

[image: draw.io schema]

```
class Group extends Model
{
    /**
     * The users that belong to the group.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

What should my `User` model look like in the other side ?

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The group that owns the user.
     */
    public function group()
    {
        return $this->???(Group::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Comment: public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
    }

Comment: @JohnLobo A user belongs to one or zero group, `belongsToMany` doesn't seem to be the method I need.

Comment: what is foo_id and bar_id  in user_group. which table id its referring

Comment: @JohnLobo It's a mistake I just fixed :-)

Comment: its belongsToMany as i said earlier. if you have issue then let me know

Comment: @JohnLobo I'm a bit puzzled, why not something like `hasOneThrough` the pivot table ?

Comment: read doc for hasOneThrough table structure you will understand better.your table structure matches belongstomany not hasonethrough

Answer (score 0):

It's also a belongsToMany, just the inverse. Try this paradigm:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Models\Group',
        'user_group',
        'user_id',
        'group_id'
    )->withTimestamps();
```

Where the explicit params are:

1. Related Model
2. Table (Pivot table)
3. Foreign Pivot Key
4. Related Pivot Key